# How to indicate your source of information is Amazon's “Alexa”?

Tags: single-word-requests, writing, phrase-requests, quotations

Is there a proper or technical way, in writing, to indicate your source of information is [Alexa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_Alexa) or some other AI (artificial intelligence)?

By this I don't mean that I have asked Alexa a factual question, such as "What is the capital of Maryland?". I mean when I am quoting her various "conversational" responses.

I am writing a paper for a class about the cultural changes that are happening with the widespread use of AI, and do not know how to correctly quote a machine.  Not one of my English books discusses this.

Comment: But wouldn't that be approximately the same thing as claiming your source is Google?

Comment: Do you mean to use Alexa as a reference and to give that official reference in a text?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about the English language. Perhaps it's better suited for Writing.SE. If you ask your question there or it gets moved there, please indicate what type of writing you want to use it in. Also note that an AI might get its information from another source, so you might want to attribute that instead.

Comment: Alexa is not the source of anything. The source would be the actual reference that Alexa returns to you—which may or may not be an appropriate source to cite. (And while verbal feedback from interview subjects is fine in a citation, Alexa's responses would not be. Unless, of course, you're writing a paper *about* Alexa. But citations would still work differently in that case . . .)